# Using reticulate with targets

Tags: r, reticulate, targets-r-package

I'm having this weird issue where my target, which interfaces a slightly customized python module (installed with `pip install --editable`) through reticulate, gives different results when it's being called from an interactive session in `R` from when targets is being started from the command line directly, even when I make sure the other argument(s) to `tar_make` are identical (`callr_function = NULL`, which I use for interactive debugging). The function is deterministic and should be returning the exact same result but isn't.

It's tricky to provide a reproducible example but if truly necessary I'll invest the required time in it. I'd like to get tips on how to debug this and identify the exact issue. I already safeguarded against potential pointer issues; the python object is not getting passed around between different targets/environments (anymore), rather it's immediately used to compute the result of interest.  I also checked that the same python version is being used by printing the result of `reticulate::pyconfig()` to screen. I also verified both approaches are using the same version of the customized module.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Not sure how I can help, but I think the process of creating a reprex may help you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: You can do `tar_target(command = {system("/usr/bin/python3 step.py") "out.txt"}, format = "file")` to run python code with a specific python interpreter and read the output of `out.txt` into another target.